# How do I change the range of a field?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am experimenting with Azure Search. I have an index with an `Edm.Double` field. I'm creating a scoring profile to boost this field via the Azure Search REST API. Currently, I have:

```
"scoringProfiles": [ 
  {
    "name":"myProfile",
    "functions": [
      {
        "type":"magnitude",
        "fieldName":"cost",
        "boost": 2.5,
        "magnitude": {
          "boostingRangeStart":0,
          "boostingRangeEnd":50
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My challenge is, I really don't know what the range of my data will be. I just always want to boost the `cost` field. In C#, I know I could use the `Double.MinValue` and `Double.MaxValue` values to scope my range. However, I'm not sure if Azure Search has constants like this available. I'm also not sure if I can use negative numbers in my scoring profile range.

Is there a way to define a scoring profile over an unknown range of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of scenario, my opinion would be to apply some kind of **bucketing** or **hashing** to the *cost* value. Or create a new attribute that is the result of the bucketing of the *cost* value (so you can still use *cost* for showing the value).

You can calculate this value on C# (using the `Double.MinValue` and `Double.MaxValue`) before adding the item to the index.

It might not be absolutely future-proof but you can always adjust if a new bucket arises due to a new higher price.

This way you can simplify the function by knowing beforehand the buckets you might be generating and boosting accordingly.

The magnitude function has a **constantBoostBeyondRange** you can use if it goes past the end of range too.

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried the `constantBoostBeyondRange` flag, however, I don't understand it. Let's say I set that flag to `true` and I have items with costs of $1.00, $3.00, $5.00, $7.00, and $10.00. Now, pretend my `boostingRangeStart` is 3.00 and my `boostingRangeEnd` is 7.00. I assume that the results with costs of $3.00, $5.00, and $7.00 would be boosted. But what about the results with the costs of $1.00 and $10.00? Are they ignored during boosting? Do $1.00 and $10.00 still get boosted? Is one boosted more than the other? Does the $10.00 get boosted but not the $1.00?

Comment: In short, I don't understand what the impact of the `constantBoostBeyondRange` flag is intended for or what it does. Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Taken form the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx): *When set to true, the full boost will continue to apply to documents that have a value for the target field that’s higher than the upper end of the range. If false, the boost of this function won’t be applied to documents having a value for the target field that falls outside of the range.*

Comment: I've seen that, but I'm not sure the docs are correct. This implies that with the example I've shown $10.00 would be boosted but $1.00 wouldn't. Is that the way you read the docs?

Comment: I understand the same thing and believe that the point is if you define a Custom Scoring with several ranges of magnitude with different scoring, this acts as a "else" in a "if" statement.